# Multiple user selects on one page - best approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

What is the best approach with ASP.Net (not AJAX) if I have several objects that have to be selected by the user.
Let's say we have to select a customer from the database (and we have millions so it should be searched with criteria before being selected) and then a material that he wants to buy (again among millions).

Should this be done in 1 page and how or in some kind of multi page wizard?

Comment: "Best" is entirely relative and subjective.  Luckily, there's a UX Stack Exchange site which may be able to help you with this, if you can provide more information about the two approaches.  Once you know the UX you're trying to achieve, Stack Overflow can help with questions about the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do the search for both customer and material with ajax i think the best option would be to keep it all on one page.

The following links explain how you can do this either with ajax "manually" with the help of JQuery or do it the web-form-way with update pannels (which is easier if you are new at it).

http://codingstill.com/2012/02/asp-net-and-ajax-all-about-update-panels-web-methods-page-methods-and-jquery/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx

Comment: ok, thanks, but that is what I don't know - AJAX, so I can't use it. With classic ASP.Net I need to do it.

Comment: Personally I like using JQuery for doing ajax calls, but if you are using asp.net webforms you can use their update pannels which basicly helps you out with doing ajax calls without having to learn ajax directly.